# why canvas size show 1 mm different from chosen size?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I create for example 12*5 cm document in new and when I select canvas size from image menu in Photoshop it show 11.99*5.01

I am using adob cs4 portable version.[image]

[image]

Comment: Which version of photoshop you are using?
Can you attach the screenshot of new document you created and canvas size dialog box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Photoshop only deals in whole pixels when sizing the canvas. 12cm x 5cm = 340.157px x 141.732px. Photoshop is simply rounding each dimension to the nearest pixel.

Comment: As a corollary to this: Why is OP creating print docs in PS?

Comment: @AMontpetit what does that have to do with anything? And where do you even see this is their entire workflow? For all you know they're doing a photo composite to import into InDesign.

Comment: @coder3641 Note how you define the size of your document in _centimetres_, but the resolution is 72 pixels per _inch_. Since centimetres and inches are quite incompatible, you’re bound to get odd measurements. If you change your resolution to be, say, 30 pixels per centimetre (which is around the same as 72 ppi), you’ll get an even number, and the size of your document will be correct. **Note:** If this is intended for printing, you should use a higher resolution, otherwise it will be horribly pixelated.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Is this the case for indesign also? I've noticed similar size changes to pages at times, be it at more unnoticeable level

Comment: @johnp: InDesign's internal measurement unit is the typographic point ... which is redefinable in its Preferences. I believe ID's *internal* internal unit is Adobe's standard approximation of 1/72th of an inch. Hence you get *some* rounding for whole-mm (or cm) values - but it will be at the very edge of the wavelength of visible light.

Comment: @johnp It shouldn’t be, no. InDesign’s native units are the physical ones; Photoshop’s is pixels. Photoshop defines documents in pixels and calculates physical sizes by dividing number of pixels by resolution. InDesign defines documents in physical units and calculates pixel size by multiplying physical size with resolution (which I believe is always 72 ppi in InDesign).

Comment: Thanks for your comments. haha @Jongware yes the rounding is hardly visible, if at all. I tend to construct grids based on pt sizes rather than mm so I get a bit fussy when modules round differently.

Comment: @Jongware You shouldn’t, beyond rounding of anything with more than three decimal points down to those three. Unlike Photoshop documents, which bases itself on a non-divisible unit (document sizes must be integer values in pixels), InDesign shouldn’t need to round anything beyond about a thousandth of a millimetre. Or was that what you meant by “the very edge of the wavelength of visible light”?

Comment: @johnp Rounding in InDesign should, unless I’m misremembering, be so small that even if you zoom all the way in to 1600%, it would still only be 0.016 mm off. That shouldn’t be visible at all at any sane zoom level. (And god help you if you usually work at 1600% zoom!)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: well you cannot set a threshold for rounding. Centimeter-to-points will always be 72/2.54; but the number of decimals is up to the size of the floating point unit that is used internally. InDesign is many magnitudes more accurate than the truncated (!) numbers you find in its dialogs.

Comment: @Jongware I’ll take your word for it—I thought document sizes were rounded down to three decimals (though I don’t recall where I got it from).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Haha, yeah, I forget how needless these alignments are at that zoom level; just have a bad habit of zooming in. You're right, indesign rounds these measurements to 3 decimal places.

Comment: @johnp: ..  *on screen only* - an important qualification. (It sounds like a great idea right until you copy/paste a value to use in the Find dialog.)